# Bad response Google Maps API

Tags: api, maps, coordinates, google-geolocation

I am using a Quectel EG25-G modem to access to Internet in a Siemens IOT2040 device (with Yocto Linux operating system). This modem is configured correctly because I haven't got any problem to access to Internet. The Quectel EG25-G modem has got a SIM card from. I have configured PPP protocol to access to Internet.

And now I want to know the geolocation using the Google API but I am not receiving good responses.

This is the command that I run: curl -d @your_filename.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=_MY_KEY_"

And in the answer I haven't got any errors:

```
{
 "location": {
  "lat": 42.4340209,
  "lng": 2.8666571999999997
 },
 "accuracy": 2818.0
}
```

The problem is that the coordenates are 500 km far for my location, and the accuracy says that the error is only 2818 m.

I am using this your_filename.json :

```
{
"cellTowers": [...]
}
```

In cellTowers I have a lot of cell towers from Spain.

First, I downloaded SQL table with this information from https://www.radiocells.org/country/es

Then, I did a query to reorganize this information in https://sqliteonline.com

```
CAST(cid AS INT) as cellId,
CAST(area AS INT) as locationAreaCode,
CAST(mcc AS INT) AS mobileCountryCode,
CAST(mnc AS INT) AS mobileNetworkCode
FROM cell_zone
WHERE area IS not -1
```

And finally, I paste the response of the query in JSON format to "cellTowers":.

I don't know why I am receiving a bad response from Google Maps API.

Thanks!

Comment: You are supposed to send the cell towers your device can currently see from the current location - not just a list of random cell towers in Spain - that will likely just give you the centroid of Spain or a random location.

Comment: From documentation:
Why am I getting a very large accuracy radius in my Geolocation response?
If your Geolocation response shows a very high value in the accuracy field, the service may be geolocating based on the request IP, instead of WiFi points or cell towers. This can happen if no cell towers or access points are valid or recognized.
To confirm that this is the issue, set considerIp to false in your request. If the response is a 404, you've confirmed that your wifiAccessPoints and cellTowers objects could not be geolocated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the different support options on the official Google Maps Platform support [1].

[1]https://developers.google.com/maps/support